# Using multiples C codes in one extension module Python

Tags: python, c, distutils, python-c-extension

I have used C code in a Python project like in [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_further_extensions.htm) tutorial.
I built an extension so that it was possible to call the `A` function present in the `main.c` code through Python. However, function `A` calls other various functions that are present in a file called `code.c`, and I'm having trouble using those functions.

**There are no problems if all the functions are placed in `main.c`, but I would like to modularize this project for organizational reasons!**

The `setup.py` for building the modules is as follows.

```
ext       =  [
                 Extension(
                 'main',
                 sources = ['main.c'] ,
                 extra_compile_args=['-lpq'] ,
                 extra_link_args = ['-L/usr/local/pgsql/lib','-lpq'],
                 language=['c']
                 )
            ]

setup(name='project', version='1.0', ext_modules = ext)
```

How could I modify it so that the `code.c` functions could be used inside `main.c` without any problems?

Here is an outline of the situation:

### main.c

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "code.h"

//....

void send(char* name)
{
   //DO SOMETHING
   function_from_code(name)
}
```

### code.c

```
.....

#include "code.h"

void function_from_code(char* name)
{
   //DO SOMETHING
}
```

and then the Python code:

```
import main

...

main.send("My Name")
```

So in this way, the python code calls the function of `module` main C (so far so good). At the moment `main.c` calls a function from `code.c`, it throws the following error:

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/main.so: undefined symbol: function_from_code
```

Apparently, using `#include` is not enough.

Comment: You ar looking for the documentation. Search somewhere on python.org.

Comment: you're calling these functions directly or are the functions in `code.c` c-functions that can be called also from Python? In the first case you could just link to "code.c" (either include or like a library) and in the latter case just "import" the "code.c" python module. In case your looking for good answers, could you provide some example of the files and how you want to call them?

Comment: @MSeifert See the EDIT. But briefly, the python code calls the function in `main.c`. And only `main.c` calls the function in `code.c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment and I'm not sure that it will fix the problem. I think it's just because it doesn't compile `code.c` and `code.h` when they are not listed explicitly as source (see ["Extension names and packages"](https://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#extension-names-and-packages)).

Personally I would use either the [`depends`](https://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#other-options) argument for the `Extension`:

```
from glob import glob

ext =  [Extension('main',
                  sources=['main.c'] ,
                  depends=glob('*.c') + glob('*.h'),
                  extra_compile_args=['-lpq'] ,
                  extra_link_args=['-L/usr/local/pgsql/lib','-lpq'],
                  language=['c']
                  )
        ]
```

or list all the files in `source`:

```
ext =  [Extension('main',
                  sources=['main.c', 'code.h', 'code.c'] ,
                  extra_compile_args=['-lpq'] ,
                  extra_link_args=['-L/usr/local/pgsql/lib','-lpq'],
                  language=['c']
                  )
        ]
```

Not sure if the order of the source files or depends files matters...

Comment: It works perfectly if you remove the `.h` from the sources list. Thanks very much my friend!!!!

Comment: @MFigueredo You're welcome. Just a question - I'm not sure if I understand your comment correctly: `sources=['main.c', 'code.c']` (without the `code.h`) worked for you?